# Grunt+karma+angular - debugging unit tests

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, webstorm, karma-runner

I have set up an angular application using Yeoman generator. It works fine, builds fine and unit tests work. I have also added Protractor for e2e tests.

I've set up Webstorm to run the unit tests as a Node.js run configuration, which executes grunt-cli\bin\grunt with the test build task. It runs fine from the IDE.

However when I'm trying to debug, the execution never stops on breakpoints.

The console output is of little help. The tests simply succeed/fail as expected and that's it.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it doesn't seem to be possible to debug protractor tests in webstorm right now. Please vote for protractor support: [WEB-9236](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-9236)

Comment: Thanks for the link. And what about debugging karma? It should work but breakpoints are never hit. Even when I had Webstorm configure the karma run config...

Comment: What WebStorm version do you use? Karma debugging is broken in WebStorm 8 (see [WEB-11577](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11577)). Bug is fixed in 8.0.1

Comment: I'm using version 7.0.3

Comment: debugging with karma run configuration works fine for me in 7.0.3. What browser do you run tests in? Debugging is supported in Chrome and Firefox only; and chrome works much better. But you need to make sure to install Chrome extension

Comment: Are you sure the browser plugin is necessary for running karma with node.js?